# XAMPPで403のエラーに関して

Tags: php, xampp

XAMPP で指定のファイルにアクセスすると下記のようなエラーが表示されます。

ググって調べましたがいまいち解決法が分かりません。
どなたか教えてください。

---

> Object not found!
>
> 要求された URL は本サーバでは見つかりませんでした。 もし手入力で URL を入力した場合は、綴りを確認して再度お試し下さい。
>
> サーバーの障害と思われる場合は、ウェブ管理者までご連絡ください。
>
> Error 404
>
> ---
>
> localhost
> Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.8 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

Comment: 具体的にどういうURLで、どこにあるファイルにアクセスしようとしたかを示すとよいと思います。